# query in .datalog input format of Z3

Tags: z3

Bddbddb supports queries of the form "Gt("a", "d")?". I added this query to the end of the example datalog program given in fixedpoints Z3 doc under the section "Basic datalog", and ran both bddbddb and Z3.  Z3 does not seem to support such syntax. Is there another syntax to query in the ".datalog" input format of Z3?